# How to fire DOM events when testing with busterjs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dom-events, buster.js

How can I trigger DOM events on an element when running in an headless browser. I know I could use jQuery's `trigger` but as I don't use for this project I don't want to use it in the test too.

Comment: Do you mean how to trigger an event natively then?

Comment: Yes. I wonder if there are any test helper library for that.